# Cognizant CITS tests ran through Bamboo: "Timed out receiving message from renderer"

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, bamboo

We have an automated test suite: Cognizant CITS, running chromedriver.exe, ran through Bamboo. The bamboo server has Chrome installed, and Chrome runs headless when Bamboo triggers the test on the build server. The test fails to take a screen shot on a failure because it's timing out. We get output like this:

```
[1553195238.924][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.337
[1553195238.925][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
[1553195248.928][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1553195258.938][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1553195258.938][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
[1553195268.941][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1553195278.948][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1553195278.949][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
```

This test suite used to take screen shots just fine, but Chrome on the build server updated itself from version 72 to 73. That's when we started seeing this issue. Google does not make earlier versions of Chrome available, so we're stuck with version 73, and updating our CITS and chromedriver.exe has not helped. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Versions we're using:

Cognizant CITS: 1.2

chromedriver.exe: 73.0.3683.68

Chrome browser: 73.0.3683.86